# ssh connection refused port 22 :: github

Tags: ssh, port, github

I have a strange problem. On one of my dev server i use git clone command to connect to github. I have set up my keys already. The connection between the dev server and github is intermittent.

When it works it works like a charm. The next minute with me doing no changes to any of the server configfurations, the connection does not work . It throws up the following error

`Initialized empty Git repository in /home/donrag/todelete/test/.git/

debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.252.129 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

I am not sure how to fix this or even where to look into. Can someone please help.

R

Answer (score 0):

Github is behind some kind of web load balancer. When you do the DNS lookup of github.com

```
dig github.com 

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     30  IN  A   192.30.252.131
```

you get a record with at most a 30 sec ttl. It's more than likely that something in your environment is holding on to the DNS record much longer than it should.
The first place I would look is nscd, it's notorious for causing these kinds of problems. Look in /etc/nscd.conf and see if you are caching the hosts records.

Comment: /etc/nscd.conf in DNS server or Dev server....cos in Dev server there is no nscd.conf

Comment: nscd is caching server for network service lookups. It would be on the dev server. http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd Another place to look is /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: this is what my nsswithch looks like `passwd:     files
shadow:     files
group:      files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns


bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   nisplus
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files nisplus
aliases:    files nisplus`

Comment: Try switching the order of the hosts line `hosts: dns files`